# SyncReadMem generated verilog vs. Rocketchip emitted verilog

Tags: chisel

I am using [SyncReadMem()](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/wiki-deprecated/memories.html#syncreadmem-sequentialsynchronous-read-sequentialsynchronous-write) for sram behavioral simulation. With the [generated Verilog by verilator](https://gist.github.com/HaFred/22a416bb0291b7dd9e2187a50cb470c0), I hope to replace it with a commercial sram compiler compiled verilog such that I can do synthesis for the whole design including sram.

However, I noticed that the verilog emitted by SyncReadMem() is not with uniform IOs just like the [sram emitted in rocketchip](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/master/scripts/vlsi_mem_gen). I wonder how do we generate some sram verilog just like the rocketchip one, using chisel mem API like SyncReadMem()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Scala FIRRTL Compiler's "Replace Sequential Memories" pass to blackbox the memories. This is exactly what is happening with Rocket Chip.

Note that this is limited to only work if the memories have a single read port and a single write port and with read latency 1 and write latency 1.

As an example, consider the following 1r1w (one read, one write) `SyncReadMem`:

```scala
import chisel3._ 

class Foo extends MultiIOModule {
  val read = IO(new Bundle {
    val en = Input(Bool())
    val addr = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val data = Output(UInt(1.W))
  })
  val write = IO(new Bundle{
    val en = Input(Bool())
    val addr = Input(UInt(8.W))
    val data = Input(UInt(1.W))
  })
  val bar = SyncReadMem(256, UInt(1.W))
  
  read.data := bar.read(read.addr, read.en)
  when (write.en) {
    bar.write(write.addr, write.data)
  }
}
```

If you compile this with a request to run the replace sequential memories pass:

```scala
(new ChiselStage)
  .emitVerilog(new Foo, Array("--repl-seq-mem", "-c:Foo:-o:Foo.mem.conf"))
```

The arguments used there are `-c:<circuit>` where `<circuit>` is the name of the circuit you want to run on and `-o:<mem-conf-file>` is the name of a file to generate that will contain information (e.g., name, width, and depth) of the memories that were blackboxed.

You wind up with the memory blackboxed inside a new module `bar` called `bar_ext`:

```
module bar(
  input  [7:0] R0_addr,
  input        R0_en,
  input        R0_clk,
  output       R0_data,
  input  [7:0] W0_addr,
  input        W0_en,
  input        W0_clk,
  input        W0_data
);
  wire [7:0] bar_ext_R0_addr;
  wire  bar_ext_R0_en;
  wire  bar_ext_R0_clk;
  wire  bar_ext_R0_data;
  wire [7:0] bar_ext_W0_addr;
  wire  bar_ext_W0_en;
  wire  bar_ext_W0_clk;
  wire  bar_ext_W0_data;
  bar_ext bar_ext (
    .R0_addr(bar_ext_R0_addr),
    .R0_en(bar_ext_R0_en),
    .R0_clk(bar_ext_R0_clk),
    .R0_data(bar_ext_R0_data),
    .W0_addr(bar_ext_W0_addr),
    .W0_en(bar_ext_W0_en),
    .W0_clk(bar_ext_W0_clk),
    .W0_data(bar_ext_W0_data)
  );
  assign bar_ext_R0_clk = R0_clk;
  assign bar_ext_R0_en = R0_en;
  assign bar_ext_R0_addr = R0_addr;
  assign R0_data = bar_ext_R0_data;
  assign bar_ext_W0_clk = W0_clk;
  assign bar_ext_W0_en = W0_en;
  assign bar_ext_W0_addr = W0_addr;
  assign bar_ext_W0_data = W0_data;
endmodule
```

You can then run a memory compiler to consume the information in the memory configuration file and drop the output in place of `bar_ext`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @seldridge, it works by replacing `bar_ext` with the compiled sram binary lib file. I wonder  how will this behavioral verilog (https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/master/scripts/vlsi_mem_gen) work for rocketchip emulator (verilator) simulation? Or it is just emitted verilog for the potential vcs verilog simulation if people are trying to do vcs simulation on rocketchip verilog?

Comment: That script will take the output memory configuration file as a parameter (`Foo.mem.conf` in the answer) and produce Verilog that should be fine for any simulator like VCS or Verilator (FPGAs should be fine, too). If you actually want to tape it out, you'll need to run a memory compiler using the information in the memory configuration file or write some script to do this for you and then replace `bar_ext` with the memory compiler output.

Comment: Ok. I guess then for the verilator simulation by issuing `cd emulator \ make`, has nothing to do with this behavioral sram verilog. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. It's used for both Verilator or VCS, but can be replaced with something technology specific if you have it. Running `cd emulator && make` or `cd vsim && make` for Rocket Chip does run that `vlsi_mem_gen` script to generate behavioral models of the SRAMs identified in the configuration file. (This shows up in a `*.behav_srsm.v` file.) You can simulate this just fine with Verilator or VCS. This step is necessary because otherwise the SRAMs will be undefined blackboxes (due to usage of `--repl-seq-mem`). For tape-out, something technology specific should be used.